# Proving something about vector spaces that seems very trivial

Tags: vector-spaces

From *Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler;* p. 19:

> Prove that if $a\in \mathbb F,v\in V$ and $av=0$, then $a=0$ or $v=0$.

Here F denotes the vector space of real and complex numbers and V is any vector space over $\mathbb F$. This means that $V$ can be denoted by $\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}, x_j\in \mathbb F$ for $j=1,2,3,...n$. I have proved this for the case when $a=0$. However the proof when $v=0$
seems incorrect to me.

Pg 8 of the same book says:

> Another type of multiplication, called scalar
> multiplication, will be central to our subject. Specifically, we need to
> define what it means to multiply an element of $F^n$ by an element of F.
> We make the obvious definition, performing the multiplication in each
> coordinate:
>
> $a(x_1, . . . , x_n) = (ax_1, . . . , ax_n);$. Here $a\in F$ and $(x_1,...x_n)\in F^n$

Coming back to the question, $av=(ax_1,ax_2 . . . , ax_n)$. If $a \neq 0$, it seems obvious to me that $v$ has to be zero (i.e all $x$ have to be zero), because that's the only way the product can be zero. However all the solutions given online are much longer than mine. What am I missing?

P.S: I have just graduated from high school, and this is my first attempt at understanding undergraduate level maths.

Comment: I think you mean $F$ is either the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. If it seems obvious, maybe the proof was intended to be very short and easy. What is your proof?

Comment: Be careful with the assumption, that  $\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}, x_j\in F$.  Unless otherwise restricted vector spaces can not only be infinite but "uncountably infinite", which says they can't be indexed using integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V=F^n$, then indeed, the proof is very short. In this case, you know that

$$av=(av_1,av_2,\dots, av_n)=(0,0,\dots)$$ and so, because $a\neq 0$, you know that $v_i=0$ for all values of $0$ and therefore, $v=0$.

---

However, the statement does not allow you to assume that $V=F^n$. The statement only requires that you assume that $V$ is a vector space over $F$. Therefore, because there exist vector spaces ovef $F$ that are not $F^n$, the statement is a stronger statement, and it makes sense that it will be harder to prove.

---

This is something you should internalize as soon as possible if you want to do well in mathematics:

> All you are allowed to assume when proving a statement are the things given in the statement .

So, in your example, you can assume the following:

1. $F$ is a field, and $a$ is an element of the field
2. $V$ is a vector space over $F$, and $v$ is a vector in $V$.
3. $a\cdot v =0$

and your proof must follow from these two assumptions (and anything that follows from them, of course).

Now, once you split the case and are looking at the case $a\neq 0$, you can do some other things. You now have (while looking at this case) the additional assumption (4: $a\neq 0$). You can now,for example, start with knowing that $$av=0$$

which you know from (3).

Well, you also know that $a$ is a nonzero element of $F$ (4), so you know it has an inverse (because (1) $F$ is a field and in a field, all nonzero elements are invertible). So, you can multiply the equation above with $a^{-1}$. And you get

$$a^{-1}(av)=a^{-1}0$$

Now, you can use some other things you know. Remember all of them must stem from the three points written above! For example, you could use the fact that in a vector space, you always have

$$\alpha(\beta u) = (\alpha\beta)(u)$$

for any two scalars $\alpha,\beta\in F$ and any vector $u\in V$. And you could also use the fact that in a vector space, for any vector $u$, you know that $$0\cdot u = 0$$
and $$1\cdot u = u.$$

This should already be enough to get you to where you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's obvious that if $a\ne0$, then $(ax_1,ax_2,\ldots,ax_n)=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ if and only if each $x_n$ is $0$. But the question is not about $F^n$. It's about an arbitrary vector space, and then you cannot just say that it's obvious. But you can say that, if $a\ne0$ and $av=0$, then$$0=a^{-1}(av)=(a^{-1}a)v=v.$$

Comment: Does this mean that $v$ can't be denoted by $\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}, x_j\in F$ for $1,2,3,...n$?

Comment: Elaborating further on my comment, if $v$ can be denoted as $\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$ then doesn't this become obvious. I can understand your method, but why do we have to go into such a lengthy proof?

Comment: Lengthy? It's one line.

Comment: Nobody is saying that $V$ is finite-dimensional. The space $V$ might be, say, the space of all polynomials in one variable over $F$ And how would you shorten my proof?

Comment: @Sunaina Yes, **if** $v$ can be denoted as $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, then it is very obvious. But what if $v$ **cannot** be denoted that way? The book you are citing shows, on page $10$, two examples of vector spaces in which vectors are not of the form $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.